# Bring value of A1 from all active sheet in to Master report

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Each sheet represents the client profile with name in F1 and email address in F3. We add a new sheet for any new client. I need to have a Master Report which will show values of F1 of all sheets (names of clients) in column A and values of F3 of all sheets(email addresses) in column B. Report needs to be updated once a new client is added.
Thank you.

Comment: This can be done in script. Would that be fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom formula:

```
function getF1F3Data() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
                             .filter(sheet => sheet.getSheetName() != 'main');
  return sheets.map(sheet => [sheet.getRange("F1").getValue(), sheet.getRange("F3").getValue()]);
}
```

[image: output]

Matches all sample data put into Sheet2 and Sheet3.